# jQuery slider gives me scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

guys. Trying to create my own gallery slider. But I have no idea how I can prevent the scrollbars. I know I have `overflow: visible` on both the wrapper and the images, but if I make it `hidden`then I won't see the images and they will get cropped off. What would be the best option here? Thanks.

```
<div id="wrapper" class="slider">


  <img src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2008/12/stock-microstock.jpg" class="slide" width="30%" alt="logo-work-example-barcelona"></img>



  <img src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2008/12/stock-microstock.jpg" class="slide" width="30%" alt="logo-work-example-apple-elephant"></img>



  <img src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2008/12/stock-microstock.jpg" class="slide" width="30%" alt="logo-work-example-animal-protect"></img>

  <img src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2008/12/stock-microstock.jpg" class="slide" width="30%" alt="logo-work-example-barcelona"></img>

<img src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2008/12/stock-microstock.jpg" class="slide" width="30%" alt="logo-work-example-barcelona"></img>

  <img src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2008/12/stock-microstock.jpg" class="slide" width="30%" alt="logo-work-example-barcelona"></img>


</div>


#wrapper {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  /*background-color: */;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  left: -1150px;
  overflow: visible;
}

#wrapper img {
  margin-left: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
}


var currentSlide = 2;
var slider = $(".slide");

      setInterval(function() {
        $(".slider").animate({position: "relative", left: "+=400px"}, 2000, function () {
          currentSlide++;
          /*$("#wrapper").css("overflow", "hidden");*/
          if (currentSlide === (slider.length - 1)) {
            currentSlide = 1;

            $(".slider").css("left", "-1150px");

          }


        });
      }, 5000);
```

My codepen: http://codepen.io/Limpuls/pen/pRbZKe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution (and actually often (always?) used when you have this type of slider) is to add one more div as container, set 100% (desired) width, and add overflow hidden to it:

```
#container {
  width:100%; //if 100%, you can even remove this line, 100% is default width
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YNWjOM

Your wrapper is pushed left too far, and can be even more, depending on number of images, and you have to hide overflow somehow.